# Getting an exception while inserting data into Excel

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, odbc, export-to-excel

I've the below HTML file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 100%;
        }
        div.ui-datepicker{
 font-size:10px;
}
    </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/development-bundle/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/development-bundle/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/development-bundle/demos.css">

</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="ToExcel.jsp">
    <div>
        <table class="auto-style1">
            <tr>
                <td>Comments</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="comments" id="comments"></td>
                <td colspan="2">No. of lines updated in PSIS</td>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="updatedl" id="updatedl"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shipment ID</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="sid" id="sid"></td>
                <td>SAP TXT Description</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="desc" id="desc"></td>
                <td>Phoenix Pub Code</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="pubcode" id="pubcode"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Product Type</td>
                <td><select name="Type" id="Type">
                  <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
                  <option value="Looseleaf - Update">Looseleaf - Update</option>
                  <option value="Pamphlet">Pamphlet</option>
                </select></td>
                <td colspan="2">Status of the job</td>
                <td colspan="2"><select name="status" id="status">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
<option value="Assigned">Assigned</option>
<option value="Completed">Completed</option>
                  <option value="From AE">From AE</option>
                  <option value="Sent to AE">Sent to AE</option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date Request received</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="DateRec" name="DateRec"></td>
                <td colspan="2">Start Date</td>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="text" id="startD" name="startD"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date assigned</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="AssignedD" name="AssignedD"></td>
                <td colspan="2">Date file sent to AE</td>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="text" id="sentToAE" name="sentToAE"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date response from AE</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="RespFrmAE" name="RespFrmAE"></td>
                <td colspan="2">Date completed --VWR</td>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="text" id="VWRCmp" name="VWRCmp"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Assigned to PS</td>
                <td><select name="PS" id="PS">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
                <option value="Amreen, Fatima (GGO)">Amreen, Fatima (GGO)</option>
                <option value="Attarwala, Nisrin (GGO)">Attarwala, Nisrin (GGO)</option>
                <option value="Balam, Santhoshini (GGO)">Balam, Santhoshini (GGO)</option>
                <option value="Bongu, Shalini (GGO)">Bongu, Shalini (GGO)</option>
                <option value="Gaddam, Sandesh R. (GGO)">Gaddam, Sandesh R. (GGO)</option>
                <option value="Grace, Shalom (GGO)">Grace, Shalom (GGO)</option>
                <option value="Johney, Liya M. (GGO)">Johney, Liya M. (GGO)</option>
                <option value="N, Steven (GGO)">N, Steven (GGO)</option>
                <option value="Varghese, Shebin D. (GGO)">Varghese, Shebin D. (GGO)</option>
              </select></td>
                <td colspan="2">Time Estimate</td>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="TEst" id="TEst"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Units</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Units" id="Units"></td>
                <td colspan="2">Date file needs to be sent to Vendor (VWR)</td>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="VWR" id="VWR"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Internal Errors</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="IE" id="IE"></td>
                <td>Review Date</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="RevDate" name="RevDate"></td>
                <td>Review Sent (Yes/No)</td>
                <td><select name="ReviewS" id="ReviewS">
                  <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
                  <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                  <option value="No">No</option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $( "#DateRec" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm-dd-y" }).val(); 
});
$(function() {
    $( "#AssignedD" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm-dd-y" }).val(); 
});
$(function() {
    $( "#RespFrmAE" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm-dd-y" }).val(); 
});
$(function() {
    $( "#RevDate" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm-dd-y" }).val(); 
});
$(function() {
    $( "#sentToAE" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm-dd-y" }).val(); 
});
$(function() {
    $( "#VWRCmp" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm-dd-y" }).val(); 
});
$(function() {
    $( "#startD" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm-dd-y" }).val(); 
});
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and submitting the data into the below jsp.

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%
Connection con = null;
Statement stmnt = null;
try
{

    String as=request.getParameter("comments");
    int a=Integer.parseInt(as);
    String bs=request.getParameter("updatedl");
    int b=Integer.parseInt(bs);
    String cs=request.getParameter("sid");
    int c=Integer.parseInt(cs);
    String d=request.getParameter("desc");
    String e=request.getParameter("pubcode");
    String f=request.getParameter("Type");
    String g=request.getParameter("status");
    String h=request.getParameter("DateRec");
    String i=request.getParameter("startD");
    String j=request.getParameter("AssignedD");
    String k=request.getParameter("sentToAE");
    String l=request.getParameter("RespFrmAE");
    String m=request.getParameter("VWRCmp");
    String n=request.getParameter("PS");
    String o=request.getParameter("TEst");
    String ps1=request.getParameter("Units");
    int p=Integer.parseInt(ps1);
    String q=request.getParameter("VWR");
    String rs=request.getParameter("IE");
    int r=Integer.parseInt(rs);
    String s=request.getParameter("RevDate");
    String t=request.getParameter("ReviewS");


Class.forName( "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver" );
con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ=C:/jus/Excel1.xls; ReadOnly=False;");


stmnt = con.createStatement(); 
//String query="select column_name from [Feb$[";
String query = "insert into [Feb$] ([comments],[No of lines updated in PSIS],[Shipment ID],"+
"[SAP TXT Description],[Phoenix Pub Code], [Product Type], [Status of the job],[Date Request received],"+
"[Start Date], [Date assigned],[Date file sent to AE],[Date response from AE],"+
"[Date completed --VWR], [Assigned to PS], [Time Estimate],[Units], [Date file needs to be sent to Vendor (VWR)],"+
"[Internal Errors],[Review Date],[Review Sent (Yes/No)]) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setInt(1,a);
ps.setInt(2,b);
ps.setInt(3,c);
ps.setString(4,d);
ps.setString(5,e);
ps.setString(6,f);
ps.setString(7,g);
ps.setString(8,h);
ps.setString(9,i);
ps.setString(10,j);
ps.setString(11,k);
ps.setString(12,l);
ps.setString(13,m);
ps.setString(14,n);
ps.setString(15,o);
ps.setInt(16,p);
ps.setString(17,q);
ps.setInt(18,r);
ps.setString(19,s);
ps.setString(20,t);

int new1=ps.executeUpdate();

}
catch( Exception e )
{
out.println( e );
}
finally
{
try
{
stmnt.close();
con.close();
}
catch( Exception e )
{
out.println( e );
}
}

        %>
```

and here when i hit submit it is giving me the below Exception.

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
```

Can anyone please let me know why am i getting this exception and where am i going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: One way to debug is try inserting one or two columns each. It is certainly a data type mismatch error. If you are using an IDE, try to debug which field is causing the problem. Try commenting out `RevDate` field and see, I am not sure though.

Comment: The issue is with the date i'm unable to understand how to insert date from java to Excel :-(

Comment: Well first you need to know what is the expected date format for excel and then parse date from java.

Comment: i gave it in the same format i use it in Excel, later it gave me exception as `unparsable date`

Comment: That is different issue, parse date in your desired format using parse methods. Google it for date parse using java. You will lots of answers. Otherwise create another question with your errors and exceptions about parsing date.